# Issues with rootViewController and Home Screen Quick Actions

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the below Objective-C code to launch my app with Home Screen Quick Actions:

```
- (void)applyShortcutItem:(UIApplicationShortcutItem *)shortcutItem
{
    ViewController *rootViewController = (ViewController *)[self.window rootViewController];

    NSLog(@"Here %@ - %@", rootViewController, shortcutItem);

    if([shortcutItem.type isEqualToString:@"LaunchMode0"])
    {
        [rootViewController setShortcutAction:LaunchMode0];
    }
    else if([shortcutItem.type isEqualToString:@"LaunchMode1"])
    {
        [rootViewController setShortcutAction:LaunchMode1];
    }
}
```

However, I keep getting runtime errors (unrecognized selected sent to instance) when I try to launch with the quick actions. Notably, it's these two lines where the app seems to trip up:

`[rootViewController setShortcutAction:LaunchMode0];` and `[rootViewController setShortcutAction:LaunchMode1];`

It doesn't seem to like the rootViewController. Technically, the initial View Controller is the Navigation Controller, however the app launches to my main view controller (the app only has two views, the main one, and an about page).

There is more code above that code in my project, but this is the part that's giving me the error-- but let me know if seeing the other code would help (I didn't want the post to be too code heavy).

Thanks so much!

EDIT: as requested, here is the complete NSLog.

```
2019-09-23 18:18:01.317271-0400 AppName[1719:200993] Here <UINavigationController: 0x108802200> - <UIApplicationShortcutItem: 0x282bd1500; type: Mode1Shortcut, title: Mode 1>
2019-09-23 18:18:01.321819-0400 AppName[1719:200993] -[UINavigationController setShortcutAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x108802200
2019-09-23 18:18:01.323462-0400 AppName[1719:200993] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setShortcutAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x108802200'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2045aa98c 0x2037839f8 0x2044c71c8 0x231033220 0x2045b01d4 0x2045b1e6c 0x102c14af0 0x102c148ec 0x230ffdf90 0x2308cc468 0x2308cd150 0x2308cc224 0x2308d0f24 0x230c012b0 0x206f275d8 0x102fecc78 0x102ff0840 0x206f61040 0x206f60cdc 0x206f61294 0x20453c728 0x20453c6a8 0x20453bf90 0x204536ecc 0x2045367c0 0x20673779c 0x231007c38 0x102c076d0 0x203ffa8e0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the complete error message. Also add the complete output of the `NSLog` statement.

Comment: *"Technically, the initial View Controller is the Navigation Controller"* - well there's your problem. `rootViewController` is a `UINavigationController`, not the view controller inside the nav controller.

Comment: @rmaddy NSLog and error have been added. I've tried various examples to set the root correctly, but all either cause Xcode errors or bugs in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
ViewController *rootViewController = (ViewController *)[self.window rootViewController];
```

But you have stated that the root view controller is a UINavigationController. You need to get your `ViewController` from the nav controller.

```
UINavigationController *rootViewController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
ViewController *viewController = (ViewController *)rootViewController.topViewController;
```

Then update the rest of the code to work on `viewController`.